# Forbidden Error - Apache

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I've edited my httpd.conf, and I'm still getting the error:

> "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this servers"

I'm trying to allow everyone to access my WAMP website. I added this into my httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After restarting my WAMP server, I'm still getting the error when I don't access my site from my local machine.

I'm using WAMPServer 2.5 which has Apache 2.4.9.

Comment: Do you have a tray icon? As normally when you install WAMP a tray icon appears allowing you to switch the site online and offline.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running i.e. WAMPServer 2,5 or an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of httpd.conf you changed protects the drive that Apache is installed on and should be set to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Now the section of `httpd.conf` that you need to look for is this one

it starts with

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
```

and inside that section there is a line like this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

To allow access from any ip address change it to this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

You should be able to do this by using the wampmanager menus like so:

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

However if you have changed the section of code around the `#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove` line, the automatic edit done by using the menus may not work, so its probably easier to do it manually, or at least check that the menu controlled edit worked properly.

Comment: The thing is, the line under the #onlineofline only showed this "Require local". I added what you told me under the #onlineoffline and it still didn't work.

Comment: Ok it would have been useful to know what version of WAMPServer(Apache) you were using. I have changed the answer to use the correct Apache 2.4 syntax

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm sorry, I didn't add the version. I updated it. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

Change DirectoryRoot to `<Directory c:/wamp/www>`
Make sure the ownership and permissions of `C:\wamp\www`

```
User: yourusername
Permission: Allow  - Read and execute and Read permissions
```

you should try this:

Edit `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` (apache2.4.9 might be different, depends on your apache version)

Scroll all the way down until you find `Deny from all` and change that too `Allow from all`

**EDIT** Answer to @Bonner

> Your permissions are still wrong

If they still wrong, please provide the right permission, instead of just point it out. Based on "my poor knowledge" I think the permission are fine.

> you have failed to ask whether the WAMP tray icon is appearing or not

Based on question description

> After restarting my WAMP server,

I assumed WAMP tray appears.

> If you make changes to the httpd-vhosts.conf they will be overwritten by the tray icon software when an option is changed

False. **WAMP Control Panel** let you edit configuration files like `my.ini`, `httpd.conf`, `php.ini`, etc.  However, you can't edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` from **WAMP Control Panel**.

Comment: This is a WAMP server, WAMP = Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP! Not Xampp, not Linux, so the information you have provided is completely wrong.

Comment: Even so, your permissions are still wrong, and you have failed to ask whether the WAMP tray icon is appearing or not, as when you install WAMP a tray icon appears allowing you to manage the server. If you make changes to the httpd-vhosts.conf they will be overwritten by the tray icon software when an option is changed.

Comment: I specified the correct permissions in the only other answer provided.

Comment: Also, the information you have provided is still incorrect, from my WAMP control panel I can edit the httpd-vhosts.conf file, and the assumptions you have made are not constructive to providing an answer.